# SE user page last sync time doesn't show UTC time on hover

Tags: feature-request, network-profile, timestamps

[image]

On the [Stack Exchange user page](https://stackexchange.com/users/current), below the About Me area, is the "Last Sync 2h ago". But when you hover over this doesn't show the UTC time it was synced - which all other times do.

Comment: To clarify, this is on the Stack Exchange _Network Profile_ page (sorry - the last edit has cleared that up). Good point (+1). Even the **Last seen**, or **seen** (on the old skool version), on the the Main User page of each SE site shows the time.  The only difference I can see, is that the Last Sync time is shown in italics, but I seriously doubt that that is the reason for its omission.

Comment: Why would this be useful? Isn't the last synced time just a rough idea?

Comment: @James everywhere else has it.

Comment: I didn't ask if it's present "everywhere else" I asked if you would find it useful :) If no-one would make use of it, then isn't it a waste of site resources loading the data, and dev time implementing/managing?

Comment: Tim, was this ever exist? I mean the UTC timestamp.

Comment: @HackerKarma  not sure

Comment: Hmmm... How would we find this now? Moderators or SE core team member can only helps us. I'm more leaning towards to know if it was exist before, if it did then why did they had it in the first base... and that would answer James question i.e. Why would this be useful?